# Reverse gradient: Integrate two 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, physics, integral

I have two 2d arrays of electric field components:

E<sub>x</sub> with (256, 512)
and
E<sub>z</sub> with (256, 512)
sizes.

I need to calculate scalar potential. Gradient of scalar potential is the electric field vector. So I need the reverse of the gradient.

I tried using the following loop to calculate the potential Φ (`phi`):

```
nx = 256
nz = 512
phi = np.zeros([nx, nz])

for i in range(1, nz):
    phi[:, i] = -dx * Ex[:, i-1] + phi[:, i-1]
    for j in range(1, nx):
        phi[j, :] = -dz * Ez[j-1, :] + phi[j-1, :]
```

This gives me an ok but weird Φ (these vertical lines are suspicious):

[image: actual result]

I expected to receive something like this (a colleague calculated the same value in Fortran and his profile is different):

[image: expected result]

This is their Fortran code:

```
allocate(phi(nx, nz))

phi(1, 1) = 0.0

do i = 2, nx
    phi(i, 1) = -dx * ex(i-1, 1) + phi(i-1, 1)
enddo

do i = 1, nx
    do j = 2, nz
        phi(i, j) = -dz * ez(i, j-1) + phi(i, j-1)
    enddo
enddo
```

Where did I make a mistake? Or is there a better way to calculate the scalar potential from an electric field?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't think that I understood you correctly.

for i in range(2,nx):
    phi[i,1]=-dz*Ez[i-1,1]+phi[i-1,1]
    for i in range(1,nx):
        for j in range (1,nz):
            phi[i,j]=-dx*Ex[i,j-1] + phi[i,j-1]
I have tried this, but the profile got worse

Comment: I don't have a solution - but if I squint, the Fortran and Python graphs have some similarity, making me think that the issue is with the `dx` and `dz` values? That is just my guess. Also, you could post this on [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) too

Comment: Does your colleague use the exact same gradient data as you ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing now is integrating the first row and then all the columns one by one (as shown on the top of the image below). The problem with this approach is that the accumulation of the error gets greater and greater the further you are from the starting point and the columns get dissociated because they don't have the same error. You can also see that you basically only use half of your data (only one component of the gradient).

[image]

To solve this you could do as suggested on the bottom of the image : integrating by going diagonally. Like that, when you are not on the border of the array, you can use two already calculated values (on the left and below) instead of one and taking the average of those should add some cohesion between the columns. If I'm correct, it would even divide the error by two.

I read your code again and I don't know how I didn't see it the first time but you are using slices. I think that's actually were your problem comes from since because of that your code isn't equivalent to your colleague's one. Your are not affecting one value at the time but whole rows/columns. Another thing I noticed is that you used Ex and dx while moving along the z axis and vice-versa.

Try this modified version of your code:

```
nx = 256
nz = 512
phi = np.zeros([nx, nz])

for i in range(1, nx):
    phi[i, 0] = -dx * Ex[i-1, 0] + phi[i-1, 0]
    for j in range(1, nz):
        phi[i, j] = -dz * Ez[i, j-1] + phi[i, j-1]
```

Comment: I understood your point. 
Would you mind showing me how the diagonally integrating loops will look for my examples?